# Drupal 6 to Pressflow migration: MyISAM to InnoDB?

Tags: 6

I will soon be migrating from Drupal 6 to Pressflow. As Pressflow encourages InnoDB for certain tables, how can I promote these recommendations when migrating an existing site?

Is this something which update.php handles?

In addition, as my Drupal site is not the latest Drupal core version, should I update to latest core first, and then sideways to the corresponding Pressflow version, or can I go straight from 6.19 to Pressflow 6.22?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine going from Drupal 6.19 to Pressflow 6.22 but make sure you backup files and database just in case.
As for converting the tables your best doing that either through mysql cli, or phpmyadmin.

I would treat these as two separate jobs: First, migrate to Pressflow and confirm the site is working; then, secondly, start moving tables.

Answer (score 1):

For converting from MyISAM to InnoDB, there are a few different methods.

You can use the [DB Tuner](http://drupal.org/project/dbtuner) module to do this straight from Drupal.

You can also take a backup (say with [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate)), change all of the `CREATE` statements, and then do a restore.

If you poke around on the main SO site, there are some methods to do this with the mysql CLI tool.

As for Pressflow, you should be able to copy your `sites/` directory into a Pressflow install, run the `update.php` script, and have everything turn out OK.

Personally, I would migrate to InnoDB, update to Drupal 6.22, and then migrate to Pressflow, but I am not sure how critical this is.